# How to solve for 2 equations 2 unknows?

Tags: equation-solving

The two equations:

3*((A^3+B^3)-(A^3+B^3)^(2/3)*B-(A^3+B^3)^(1/3)*A^2+A^2*B)=A^3+B^3+(A^3+B^3)+3*(A+B+(A^3+B^3)^(1/3))*(AB+A(A^3+B^3)^(1/3)+B(A^3+B^3)^(1/3))-3AB(A^3+B^3)^(1/3)

(A^3+B^3)^3-A^2-B^2=(A((A^3+B^3)^(1/3)-A)((A^3+B^3)^(1/3)-B))+(((A^3+B^3)^(1/3)-B)*(A^3+B^3)^(2/3))+((B-A)((A^3+B^3)^(1/3)-B)(A^3+B^3)^(1/3))+(B((A^3+B^3)^(1/3)-A)((A^3+B^3)^(1/3)-B))+(((A^3+B^3)^(1/3)-B)((A^3+B^3)^(1/3)-(A+B))(B-A))

The two unknowns: A,B

how to solve these 2 equations 2 unknowns.

Answer (score 2):

There are typos wherein `A*B` is written as `AB` (a new variable). Also I follow the common practice of avoiding upper case. Finally, notice that there is a dimensional solution if `a` and `b` are zero. I add a polynomial to force neither to be zero. Allowing one or the other to vanish can readily be done separately.

With that, here is the corrected input.

```
ee = {-2*a^3 - 2*b^3 + 3*a*b*(a^3 + b^3)^(1/3) - 
    3*(a + b + (a^3 + b^3)^(1/3))*
           (a*b + a*(a^3 + b^3)^(1/3) + b*(a^3 + b^3)^(1/3)) - 
         3*(a^3 + a^2*b + b^3 - a^2*(a^3 + b^3)^(1/3) - 
       b*(a^3 + b^3)^(2/3)), 
       -a^2 - 
    b^2 + (a^3 + b^3)^3 - (-a + 
       b)*(a^3 + b^3)^(1/3)*(-b + (a^3 + b^3)^(1/3)) - 
         (a^3 + b^3)^(2/3)*(-b + (a^3 + b^3)^(1/3)) - 
    a*(-a + (a^3 + b^3)^(1/3))*
           (-b + (a^3 + b^3)^(1/3)) - 
    b*(-a + (a^3 + b^3)^(1/3))*(-b + (a^3 + b^3)^(1/3)) - 
         (-a + b)*(-b + (a^3 + b^3)^(1/3))*(-a - 
       b + (a^3 + b^3)^(1/3)), a*b*recip - 1};
```

It can be solved numerically.

```
nsols = NSolve[ee == 0, {recip, a, b}];
Length[nsols]
Chop[ee /. nsols]

(* Out[28]= 43

Out[29]= {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
   0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

I do not know how long an exact solution might take.